# Log4net does not log thru powershell execution of console app

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, log4net

I have a .net console app which has logging implementation using `log4net` library. It works properly when I execute this console application's executable thru command prompt.

However with recent requirement of out infrastructure, we have to execute console application executable thru `PowerShell`.  In this situation, application works properly however it dot not write anything into the log file.

Any idea what is missing or what changes required to enable logging like earlier thru `PowerShell` without changing application?

Comment: I believe it's a permission problem. Please check who is the log folder "owner" and what kind of rights you have there.

Comment: Be aware that if you're using a relative path in the `log4net` config, it'll be resolved relative to the working directory of the process, which is _not_ necessarily the path you've navigated to in PowerShell